# Passport js password reset Using Express and Mongo

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, change-password, password-hash

I'm using passport  to register and authenticate users. I'm trying to let users change their passwords. I'm using vanilla passport setup with no customisation, and when a new user is registered it automatically generates a salt and hash.

I have username, salt and old (forgotten password) hash in my database, but I don't understand how to generate the new hash with the new password. Is there a passport method/command????

Thanks

Comment: check this tutorial for step by step process to reset password http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/

Comment: @zerosand1s Thanks for the link. I wil try to apply this. I'm a little confused. Since I can use  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user) {callback} to 1. Create user in Mongo, 2.Generate salt and 3 Hash the password, surely there is a passport command I can use to do 2 and 3 to an existing user?????

Comment: @zerosand1s that psycho put the whole backend in one file..